# ValueError: Dimension (-1) must be in the range [0, 2) in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Suddenly  I have this error with kears with tensorflow backend (python2.7) , same error with every code. I thought its keras 1 and 2 incompatibility but it was not

```
Dimension (-1) must be in the range [0, 2), where 2 is the number of dimensions in the input. for 'metrics/acc/ArgMax' (op: 'ArgMax') with input shapes: [?,?], [].
```

'I update both tensorflow and keras like similar problem (link ↓↓) but still same error 
[ValueError: Dimension (-1) must be in the range [0, 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202037/valueerror-dimension-1-must-be-in-the-range-0-2) 
The full code (example)

```
**Code updated the whole code** 

using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA   library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA   library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA  library libcurand.so locally
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               401920    
 _________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 10)                5130      
=================================================================
Total params: 669,706
Trainable params: 669,706
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_mlp.py", line 48, in <module>
    metrics=['accuracy'])
  File "/home/usr/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 784, in compile
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 924, in compile
    handle_metrics(output_metrics)
  File "/home/usr/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 921, in handle_metrics
    mask=masks[i])
  File "/home/usr/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 450, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/usr/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 25, in categorical_accuracy
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
  File "/home/usr/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1333, in argmax
    return tf.argmax(x, axis)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 249, in argmax
    return gen_math_ops.arg_max(input, axis, name)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 168, in arg_max
    name=name)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2242, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1617, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1568, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
  File "/home/usr/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)
ValueError: Dimension (-1) must be in the range [0, 2), where 2 is the number of dimensions in the input. for 'metrics/acc/ArgMax' (op: 'ArgMax') with input shapes: [?,?], [].'
```

Comment: Are you using a 'categorical_crossentropy' or a 'softmax' or a 'RMSprop'? What is the shape of your `y_train` (labels/true values/targets)?

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this MLP example to make my problem more clear https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py

Comment: What is your last layer? Is it "exactly" that code?

Comment: Could you post the code that is throwing the error?

Comment: I posted the whole error with the code https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py .. I'm getting this error with each code. Not sure where is the problem with tensorflow or keras

Answer (score 3):

I just started playing with Keras and I incurred in the same problem. I followed the different workarounds proposed on different forums - including running an upgrade of tensorflow/keras itself - but that did not seem to work for me.

The problem seems to be that the argmax function in Keras. backend is called, by default, with a axis=-1, which is out of range, given that only [0, 2) are legit.

My solution has been rewriting the categorical accuracy function:

```
import keras.backend as K

def get_categorical_accuracy_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=1), K.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)))
```

(I found the formula in [this thread](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/how-does-keras-calculate-accuracy))

which should be equivalent to the following function, which leverages numpy library:

```
import numpy as np

def get_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return (np.argmax(y_true, axis=1) == np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)).mean()
```

Using `get_categorical_accuracy_keras` function in the model compilation:

```
model.compile(loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=[get_categorical_accuracy_keras])
```

seems to solve the problem.

Of course, I would like to use the already defined accuracy myself, so any suggestion in that sense is welcome

Comment: I was able to use this method to get accuracy. However, when trying to load a saved model using this metric, 'Unknown metric function:get_categorical_accuracy_keras' error is thrown. I used 'load_model' from keras.model...

Comment: I passed an custom object while loading the model. It worked out fine. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I faced same error message (due to default Digital Ocean app) when tried to load a already saved model from my mac to DigOcean. Updated tensorflow using:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and 1.3.0 was installed and the problem got resolved when I restarted the jupyter kernel.